# Обновление данных на странице не перезагружая ее

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Вопрос скорее теоретический. Допустим у меня есть страница, с этой страницы на нее же я отправляю POST данные, после чего по ним уже отображается соотвествующие блоки.

ЭТО просто ПРИМЕР

```html
<ul>
  <li>
  <form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="view" value="1">
  <input type="submit" value="Сотрудники">
  </form>
  </li>
 <li>
  <form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="view" value="1">
  <input type="submit" value="Сотрудники">
  </form>
  </li>
</ul>
if (id==1) {
div такой то 
}elst if (id==2) {
еще какие то данные
}
```

ВОПРОС

так как я новичок, хотел бы узнать как правильно реализововать данный пример не обновляя самой страницы (и вообще правильно ли я делаю что передаю POST данные), или все это делается через библиотеки JAVASCRIPTA, только начал учить vue.js там постепенно это выресовывается, НО хотел бы узнать можно ли сделать это простыми способами, чтоб не обновлял страницу (Я НОВИЧОК!)

Comment: можете дать информацию на источники любые, чтоб я почитал

Comment: нет, php - отработал, отдал страницу и завершил свою работу. динамические страницы создаются средствами только JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого надо воспользоваться расширением AJAX(Асинхронный JavaScript и XML:

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

Вы отправляете на сервер POST запрос, и получаете ответ (для PHP, например, это вывод скрипта при помощи echo)

Это должно выглядеть вот так

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({url: "test.php", success: function(result){
            $("#div1").html(result);
        }});
    });
});
</script>
```

test.php

```
if (id==1) {
    echo "<div id=\"1\">Div 1 c данными</div>"
}else if (id==2) {
    echo "<div id=\"2\">Div 2 c данными</div>"
}
```

Comment: спасибо, попробую сделать

Comment: а если в дивах данные с базы данных он обновит их ?

Comment: Вы обновите кусочек страницы тем что сами положите в ответ WEB-сервера, не важно что это будет, кусок HTML кода, ответ из БД или просто текст.

Comment: Аааа никогда не возвращай текст в ajax возвращай JSON. А то потом будут вопросы как с этим работать.